# UILabel - How to add space between lines in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsparagraphstyle, line-spacing

I've UILabel with paragraphic information (multiline text) and I want add some spaces between lines, similar to this image.

[image: this image]

Please help me to do it. I've tried to checkout all documentation of apple developer regarding Label and line spacing but could find.

Comment: What have you tried?  Post reproducible code so people can help you.  To improve your question to get better responses read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Thanks  Brian O'Donnell, for your suggestion. I saw it. I new to this site, so was not aware completed with question answer pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**From Interface Builder (Storyboard/XIB):**

[image]

**Programmatically:**

**SWift 4**

Using label extension

```
extension UILabel {

    // Pass value for any one of both parameters and see result
    func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

        guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString
        if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
        } else {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
        }

        // Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Now call extension function

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"

// Pass value for any one argument - lineSpacing or lineHeightMultiple
label.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0) .  // try values 1.0 to 5.0

// or try lineHeightMultiple
//label.setLineSpacing(lineHeightMultiple = 2.0) // try values 0.5 to 2.0
```

Or using label instance (Just copy & execute this code to see result)

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40

// Line spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// Character spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

**Swift 3**

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Sample text"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))
label.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: That Swift 4 extension is __awesome__. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
let textForLabel = “Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text 
ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five 
centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining 
essentially unchanged.”

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
//line height size
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.4
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleText)
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, 
range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
myLabel.attributedText = attrString
myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

[image]